# How to add common callback for all the animations in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, callback

I am currently developing a web page that contains many animations.

code sample

```
<div id="a1">
    <img src="aaa/Test1.png" style="display:none;" id="img1"/>
</div>
<div id="a2">
    <img src="aaa/Test2.png" style="display:none;" id="img2"/>
</div>
<div id="a3">
    <img src="aaa/Test3.png" style="display:none;" id="img3"/>
</div>
<script>        
    $("#img1").fadeIn(3000);
    $("#img2").fadeIn(3000);
    $("#img3").animate({
             'marginLeft' : "0px"
        }, 2000);
</script>
```

I want to add common callback that called after each animation end. I don't want to write like

```
$("#img1").fadeIn(3000,function(){callback();});
$("#img2").fadeIn(3000,function(){callback();});
$("#img3").animate({
   'marginLeft' : "0px"
}, 2000,function(){callback();});
```

I just want add callback as a whole (like giving style to all div in jquery $('div').css("height","100px");)

Is there any code like this for giving callback to all animations in a page?

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to bind every each `img`? If the binding attributes are the same it would be better to give them a class and target that.

Anyway:

```
$("#img1").fadeIn(3000,callback); //notice the use of the function name without trailing "()"
$("#img2").fadeIn(3000,callback);

function callback() {
//you can use $(this) here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not aware of i can use $(this) in callback.

Answer (score 1):

ID is used to make item unique indentifier. Use classes

change all image tags and add class

```
<img src="aaa/Test1.png" style="display:none;" class="my_img"/>
```

then in jquery use

```
$(".my_img").fadeIn(3000,function(){callback();});
```

or anything u want. This code binds fadeIn to all items with class "my_img" if you want to bind it to all images inside div that has my_img class u can use

```
$("div img.my_img").fadeIn(3000,function(){callback();});
```